# In emacs, how do I highlight and flash current line with a changing backcolor as the following video did?

Tags: emacs, highlight

In this video: Org-roam-bibtex - Quick Presentation][1](https://youtu.be/Wy9WvF5gWYg), the background color of the active line will be temporarily changed and flashed. Can anyone call tell me how to do it, pelase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is [Beacon mode](https://github.com/Malabarba/beacon). It eases finding the cursor (point) when changing windows or when scrolling.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thank you so much.